# How to keep each celery class based task in separate file in django project?

Tags: python, django, celery, class-based-tasks

I have setup celery in my django project using official documentation at
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

So my project structure is

```
└── mysite
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── celery.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── polls
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── forms.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── migrations
        │   ├── 0001_initial.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── tasks.py
        ├── tests.py
        └── views.py
```

`polls` is application
`polls/tasks.py` have class based celery task.
Currently `tasks.py` have many tasks so that file is too big. I want to keep each task in separate file like

```
mysite/polls/
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── tasks # I want to keep easy task in separate file like this
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── download_task.py
│   ├── process_task.py
│   └── upload_task.py
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

How to make this setup working?

Answer (score 3):

That is 100% correct.  In your `tasks/__init__.py` file, make sure to import the tasks from the other files:

```
    from .download_task import *  
    from .process_task import *
    # etc...
```

And then make sure you have the `autodiscover_tasks` call in your celery.py file to discover the tasks in each of your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

#### **2023 Update**

You can set the autodiscover_tasks in your celery.py to look up other files.

eg.
app.autodiscover_tasks(related_name='tasksv2')

This will search for 'taskv2.py' in your apps folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).